# Не добавляются элементы в массив

Tags: массивы, битрикс, php

Добрый день.

Делаю сайт на битриксе, довольно типовая задача, есть инфоблок с разделами и элементами, в публичную часть элементы выводятся с помощью компонента `news.list`, в нём (из коробки) нет  группировки по разделам. Добавил файлик `result_modifier.php`, пишу такой код:

```
  //Группируем элементы по разделам
$itemsArray = Array();

//Запихиваем секции (разделы инфоблока) в массив
$Sections = CIBlockSection::GetList(array(), array("IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "ID" => array_keys($arSectionIDs)));
while($secItem = $Sections->GetNext())
    {
        $itemsArray[$secItem["ID"]] = $secItem["NAME"];
    }

//Раскидываем  по секциям

foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $Item)
    {
        //$var = $Item["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"];
            //Вот такую опирацию делал много раз на разных проектах и всегда всё работало, сейчас выдаёт ошибки
        //$itemsArray[$Item["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]]["ITEMS"][] = $Item;   //Cannot use string offset as an array in
        //array_push($itemsArray[$var]["ITEMS"], $Item); //Only variables can be passed by reference in
        //$itemsArray[$Item["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]]["ITEMS"][] = $Item;
    }

    if($USER->IsAdmin())
        {
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($itemsArray);
            //echo "</pre>";
        }

//Сохраняем элменты сгрупперованные по разделам
    $arResult["ITEMS_TO_SECTIONS"] = $itemsArray;

    unset($itemsArray);
```

Всегда добавлял новые элементы в массив в цикле вот так:

```
$itemsArray[$Item["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]]["ITEMS"][] = $Item;
```

и всегда работало, сейчас ошибка **Cannot use string offset as an array in**, так тоже
не работает:

```
$var = $Item["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"];    
array_push($itemsArray[$var]["ITEMS"], $Item);
```

ошибка **Only variables can be passed by reference in**.

Точно такой же код работает на другом проекте, версия php там **5.3.28** , а тут **5.3.3-7+squeeze17**. Думаю, что причина в различных версиях, но как элементы в массив в таком случае добавлять, не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

```
$itemsArray[$secItem["ID"]] = $secItem["NAME"];
```

$secItem["NAME"] возвращает string?

Попробуйте так:

```
$itemsArray[$secItem["ID"]][] = $secItem["NAME"];
```

Comment: Ошибка в коде ниже тут:

`$itemsArray[$Item["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]]["ITEMS"][] = $Item;`

Comment: Если $secItem["NAME"] string, тогда вы записываете в элемент массива string, а потом пытаетесь его использовать как массив.